# Lilypond: Avoid clash between group and instrument names

Tags: lilypond

I'm absolutely new to lilypond and I find it extremely powerful. However, since it's my first time I'm using it I have a simple question.

Suppose I'm writing something for two group of instruments (here heckelphones and bassoons) I want to put the name of the groups, and also the name of each part (1,2,3 for heckelphones and 1,2,C for the bassoons). I wrote the following code:

```
\version "2.18.2"


scoreAGlobal = {
  \key c \major
  \time 4/4
}

scoreAOboeI = \relative c'' {
  \scoreAGlobal
  % Music follows here.

}

scoreAOboeII = \relative c'' {
  \scoreAGlobal
  % Music follows here.

}

scoreAOboeIII = \relative c'' {
  \scoreAGlobal
  % Music follows here.

}

scoreABassoonI = \relative c {
  \scoreAGlobal
  % Music follows here.

}

scoreABassoonII = \relative c {
  \scoreAGlobal
  % Music follows here.

}

scoreAContraBassoon = \relative c {
  \scoreAGlobal
  \transposition c
  % Music follows here.

}

scoreAOboeIPart = \new Staff \with {
  instrumentName = "1"
  shortInstrumentName = "1"
  midiInstrument = "oboe"
} \scoreAOboeI

scoreAOboeIIPart = \new Staff \with {
  instrumentName = "2"
  shortInstrumentName = "2"
  midiInstrument = "oboe"
} \scoreAOboeII

scoreAOboeIIIPart = \new Staff \with {
  instrumentName = "3"
  shortInstrumentName = "3"
  midiInstrument = "oboe"
} \scoreAOboeIII

scoreABassoonIPart = \new Staff \with {
  instrumentName = "1"
  shortInstrumentName = "1"
  midiInstrument = "bassoon"
} { \clef bass \scoreABassoonI }

scoreABassoonIIPart = \new Staff \with {
  instrumentName = "2"
  shortInstrumentName = "2"
  midiInstrument = "bassoon"
} { \clef bass \scoreABassoonII }

scoreAContraBassoonPart = \new Staff \with {
  instrumentName = "C."
  shortInstrumentName = "C."
  midiInstrument = "bassoon"
} { \clef bass \scoreAContraBassoon }

\score {
  <<
    \new StaffGroup <<
      \set StaffGroup.instrumentName = "Heckelphones"
      \scoreAOboeIPart
      \scoreAOboeIIPart
      \scoreAOboeIIIPart
    >>
    \new StaffGroup <<
      \set StaffGroup.instrumentName = "Bassoons"
      \scoreABassoonIPart
      \scoreABassoonIIPart
      \scoreAContraBassoonPart
    >>
  >>
  \header {
    piece = "1."
  }
  \layout { }
  \midi {
    \tempo 4=100
  }
}
```

It is almost perfect but the name of the group miserably clashes with the name of the part. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use `\vspace` to scoot one or the other `instrumentName` out of the way e.g. instead of

```
instrumentName = "2"
```

say

```
instrumentName = \markup { \vspace #2 "2" }
```